# C code printing hex values but very different

Tags: c, printing

```
int main() {
        int i;
        int four_ints[4];
        char* c;

        for(i=0; i<4; i++) four_ints[i] = 18;

        c = (char*)four_ints;
        for(i=0; i<4; i++) c[i] = 24;

        printf("%x\n", four_ints[2]);
    }
```

So if I print like that it will simply print 12.

However if I change it to `printf("%x\n", four_ints[11])`

It suddenly prints `28ac90`

Why would it do that?

Comment: Because index 11 is way outside your four integer array and totally undefined?

Comment: In the second statement `printf("%x\n", four_ints[11])` you access a position of the array that was not reserved for your program (`int four_ints[4]`)

Comment: @GustavoTorres You should consider posting your answer as an answer rather than in the comments to notify future viewers that this question was answered.

Comment: @kelberry just did it. I just wasn't sure if such a small answer was appropriate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second statement `printf("%x\n", four_ints[11])` you access a position of the array that was not reserved for your program (`int four_ints[4]`). That is you have no guarantees of what is stored on a not reserved portion of memory.